# Kotlin - Data class type String or some Object

Tags: kotlin

Say I have this data class in Kotlin:

```
@Document(collection = Approval.COLLECTION)
data class Approval(
    @Id
    val id: String,
    val detailId: <UNSURE HERE>
) {
    companion object {
        const val COLLECTION: String = "approval"
    }
}
```

That `detailID` can either be a `String` or an object like so:

```
data class AIDConfiguration(
    val sId: String,
    val cId: String
)
```

However how do go about setting that type - as I can't use something like

```
val detailId: AIDConfiguration | String
```

I thought maybe make an interface, but not sure any syntax of getting that to be just a String

```
interface ParentConfiguration

data class AIDConfiguration(
    val sId: String,
    val cId: String
): ParentConfiguration
```

And then

```
val detailId: ParentConfiguration
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not using a sealed class?

Answer (score 0):

One way could be:

```
val detailId: Any
```

This is loose cause it will allow any type to be assigned to detailId.
So before usage you would have to check for the type.

```
fun useConfig(detailId: Any) {
    if (detailId is AIDConfiguration) {
        //Use detailId.sId and detailId.cId. Compiler smart casts to AIDConfiguration
    } else if (detailId is String)
        //Use detailId. Compiler will smart cast to String
    } else {
        //throw some exception here.
    }
}
```

You might want to use some validations when setting the configuration as well. Check whether the type is `AIDConfiguration` or `String`.

A little more tighter would be to have a parent configuration class. Such as `ParentConfiguration` and have `AIDConfiguration` and `StringConfiguration` as subclasses.

So then it becomes:

```
interface ParentConfiguration

data class AIDConfiguration(
    val sId: String,
    val cId: String
): ParentConfiguration

data class StringConfiguration(
    val conf: String
): ParentConfiguration

data class Approval(
    val id: String,
    val detailId: ParentConfiguration
)

val stringConfigApproval = Approval(id = "Test1", detailId = StringConfiguration("String Conf"))
val aidConfApproval = Approval(id = "Test2", detailId = AIDConfiguration(sId = "SID", cId = "CID"))
```

Would recommend checking out the kotlin docs.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/inheritance.html
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin being a statically typed language, you can't just specify multiple types. An interface is a good option to do so, but since String is not implemented by you, you cannot change its signature.

One of the work around should be to use [Either](https://medium.com/@Robert_Chrzanow/kotlins-missing-type-either-51602db80fda) like [this](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture-Kotlin/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/com/fernandocejas/sample/core/functional/Either.kt):

```kotlin
sealed class Either<out L, out R> {

    data class Left<out L>(val a: L) : Either<L, Nothing>()

    data class Right<out R>(val b: R) : Either<Nothing, R>()

    /**
     * Returns true if this is a Right, false otherwise.
     * @see Right
     */
    val isRight get() = this is Right<R>

    /**
     * Returns true if this is a Left, false otherwise.
     * @see Left
     */
    val isLeft get() = this is Left<L>

    /**
     * Applies fnL if this is a Left or fnR if this is a Right.
     * @see Left
     * @see Right
     */
    fun fold(fnL: (L) -> Any, fnR: (R) -> Any): Any =
        when (this) {
            is Left -> fnL(a)
            is Right -> fnR(b)
        }
}
```

And then specify your variable like this:

```kotlin
val detailId: Either<AIDConfiguration, String>
```

And when you want to do some specific operation, just call the fold method like:

```kotlin
detailId.fold({ /* use $it as AIDConfiguration */ }, { /* use $it as String */ })
```

**EDIT:** You could also make aliases for your purpose in your projects for better readability check https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html